# How does between?(min, max) method work for string?

Tags: ruby

I have a doubt on `between?(min, max)` method. How does it actually work for string? Could anyone of you explain this?

```
'cat'.between?('ant', 'dog')   #=> why this is true?
'gnu'.between?('ant', 'dog')   #=> why this is false?
'acasdsdc'.between?('acaassdc','awadssde') #=> why this is true?
```

Thanks!

Comment: Lexicographic ordering. `c` is between `a` and `d`. What else would you expect?

Comment: Does it check for an only first letter? Because the 2nd letter is not in Lexicographic order. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: "Does it check for an only first letter?" – No, it doesn't. It checks lexicographically, i.e. first the first letter, then the second letter, then the third, and so on. That is what "lexicographic" *means*: ordered like in a lexicon.

Comment: Since `cat` begins with c, it is lexicograhpically after `ant` and before `dog`. The second and third letters do not matter. If you had another word beginning with a, such as `art`, then the second letter would be checked to see if it is before or after the second letter of `ant`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F), `Comparable#between?` looks at the value of `comparable_object.<=>` for the min and max values in the range.

In other words, [in this case](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), it performs a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) check - i.e. **"which word comes first in a dictionary?"**

In a dictionary, those words appear in the order: `ant`, `cat`, `dog`, `gnu`.

Therefore `cat` is between `ant` and `dog`, but `gnu` is not.